# Login using requets.post not working - Errors 400, 404 and 405

Tags: python

I'm trying to login to a local supermarket's webpage for a web scraping project I'm working on. Unfortunately I can't access the store without logging in, so I need to post a login request and then load the appropriate URL to scrape with BeautifulSoup.

Here's the code I wrote:

```html
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36'}

landing_URL = 'https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/applicationCheck?appName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light#!/negozio/'

payload = {'gw_username': 'xxx', 'gw_password': 'yyy'}

r = requests.post(landing_URL, payload, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code)
```

Now, the login line from the source code goes like:

```html
<form id="loginForm" action="/area-utenti/loginExt" method="post" onsubmit="return checkCaptchaAndLogin();" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

I tried adding /loginExt in various parts of the URL to post the login requests but none work, most of the times I get request not supported.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'd say that `checkCaptchaAndLogin` was a pretty big clue on why this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the action is action="/area-utenti/loginExt" and thus submits the data to mywebsite.com/area-utenti/loginExt. Just adding /loginExt won't do much.

Second, you have the 'onsubmit ="return checkCaptchaAndLogin();"' attribute, which means that when you submit the form, the checkCaptchaAndLogin function is called, and probably overrides the submit action. Also, by the name of the function, I can guess that you have to solve a captcha in order to log in.

Without more information it is difficult to say.

Comment: OK so then the URL is https://www.esselunga.it/area-utenti/loginExt/applicationCheck?appName=esselungaEcommerce&daru=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.esselungaacasa.it%3A443%2Fecommerce%2Fnav%2Fauth%2Fsupermercato%2Fhome.html%3F&loginType=light#!/negozio/.

The problem is that there's no captcha when logging in manually, nor the site has ever shown one to me even if I wrote an incorrect password (I've been using the site for a year btw).

Comment: The form triggers the URL esselunga.it/area-utenti/loginExt. If it then performs a redirect or the function **checkCaptchaAndLogin** does something, I don't know. Try looking in the javascript (check the console or inspector, depending on your browser) and see what it does